# How to receive messages using the new Google Cloud Messaging Api for Android?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have found tons of tutorials explaining Google Cloud Messaging but all seem deprecated with the new [Google Cloud Messaging Api](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html)
In fact I cannot get a valid registration id using the **deprecated GcmRegistrar** class!
While using the new api I can get a valid registration id and use that to perform successful requests from my server to google.

I am lost as to how will I implement a **Receiver** in the Android App that will enable me to actually use the received messages.
*I guess GCMBaseIntentService and all relevant code is now deprecated and implemented in another way*

The google docs are referring to this:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:exported="true"
 android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <category android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME" />
 </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

So how could I implement this **MyReceiver**?

Comment: The old API (`GCMRegistrar`, `GCMBaseIntentService`) still works (I just tested it), so I find it strange that you couldn't get a Registration ID when using it. That said, of course it makes more sense to use the new GoogleCloudMessaging API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was much simpler than I thought.
You no longer need gcm.jar nor gcm-server.jar.
No need for a special service like `GCMIntentService`
No need for the receiver to handle this action: `com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION`

Actually a developer now needs to implement his own BroadcastReceiver which is as simple as that:
*in [Scala](https://github.com/yareally/android-scala-intellij-no-sbt-plugin)*

```
class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  def onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    log log "we have received something!";
    val extraString = Option(intent.getStringExtra("json label here"));
    log log "the value of this json label is: " + extraString;
  }
}
```

Comment: Mentioning `gcm-server.jar` here is irrelevant. `gcm-server.jar` has never been needed in the client application. It's only used in the 3rd-party server (assuming you use the HTTP request mechanism to send messages), and even then you don't have to use it.

Comment: Well as you can imagine I am just starting to getting to know gcm so I blindly followed the tutorials but thanks for pointing this out.